How to Create Extra Meta using Typescipt
I could not find a way using typescript to create extra metadata for the transfer hook program.
I can initiate the Tranferhook Instruction using
createInitializeTransferHookInstruction(mint, payer.publicKey, transferHookProgramId, TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID)

However, How do I perform the following task using typescript?
spl-transfer-hook create-extra-metas <Transfer_Hook_Program_ID> <Mint_Address>


There are no JS bindings for creating the extra account metas in TypeScript, so you'll have to write the lib yourself unfortunately. The Rust source code for reference lives at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/d1c03cc6164ebdeebef19190de28b7a71f4e4cb6/token/transfer-hook/interface/src/instruction.rs#L36
